# Get service file information using docker container id

Tags: docker, coreos

I want to be able to get some information on the service file that created the docker process from the container id.

The flow:

```
fleetctl start myapp.service1
fleetctl start myapp.service2
fleetctl start myapp.service3

docker ps --no-trunc
  for each container id on each record
     find the service name it was created with
```

I would appriciate any solution or work around like set an environment variable using the service file, and pull it later on using the docker container id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the container names. Have `myapp1.service` contain `docker run --name myapp1` as the ExecStart and then you'll be able to find it with `docker ps`.

Comment: Thanks, it's sound like a good approach, but I hoped for a solution that I can extend for more information, like using environment variables. what do you think? is it possible? set en environment during fleetctl start or inside the service file and somehow pull it later on from the running docker.

Comment: It's possible. You want to read more about `docker inspect` command. https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#inspect